# SQL Server table names list in sequence

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bcp

I have to export all tables from database and then import them back. I generated a `bcp` command via SQLAzureMW tool and the tool somehow order the tables in proper way to avoid FKs dependency issues. I don't think this tool has an option to generate them via cmd or something and I'm not able to use UI in my scenario. So the question is can I get the list of the tables in that order via T-SQL?

I'm also not able to use backup/restore approach so I'm looking for other ways to accomplish the task. BCP works really fast and i prefer it, but I don't want to hardcode the order of the tables, if someone add new table with dependencies the script will no longer work.

Comment: Rather than trying to build your own solution, why not create a backup or use a DACPAC?

Comment: because i have to do that with script , it will be part of CI/CD , i'm not able to use UI. DACPAC i'm not sure if can be generated and then executed via TSQL ?

Comment: *"because i have to do that with script "* Why? *Why* **must** it with with a sql script?

Comment: Check out this article: https://dataedo.com/kb/query/sql-server/list-foreign-keys

Answer (score 0):

This stored procedure :

```
EXEC sp_msdependencies @flags = 8
```

helped me and give me the correct order, then i just did export/import via bcp and proper order and everything works as expected.